# Nested JSON parsing in C#

Tags: c#, json

Hi I have a simple nested json and am trying to parse it with Javascriptserializer(). I created a class with properties and one more class for another nested data. But am not able to access full properties

I have tried the below code

This works well  and below is my class where am saving this content

when i do

Comment: try with this `inputStreamingData.infoData.ImageType`. because  `infoData` not an array.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to use JSON.NET (not JavascriptSerializer) in the [mcve]. The [mcve] must include the JSON string **defined in code**. The [mcve] must be able to be copied and pasted into a new console app and run **as is** without further modification (test this for yourself **before** sharing it with us). I'd suggest using https://app.quicktype.io/?share=FJiVix5fXLHeq51FS1CU as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code.

I have tried with [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonData ="{\"Command\":\"te\",\"Data\":{\"Image\":\"/6D/ogARAP8\",\"Imagetype\":\"FLS\",\"Imageformat\":\"bmp\",\"MissingFingers\":[\"FLIF\",\"FLMF\"]}}";
        var jsonRootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonRootObject.Data.MissingFingers[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonRootObject.Data.Imagetype);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonRootObject.Data.Image);
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Imagetype { get; set; }
        public string Imageformat { get; set; }
        public List<string> MissingFingers { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string Command { get; set; }
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Like demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RQw84V)

Comment: this demo is for your question. If you changes into your json and json is not valid than you got error.
So give me your `real json` I will help you.

Comment: It's working fine with your `real json` as well check demo link